# Filter pyspark DataFrame when column text contains more then 10 words

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, pyspark

I have a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` and I want to keep (filter) all rows where one of my columns (called text) has more then 10 words.

I have tried 
`df = df.filter(len(df.text.split())>10)` but this throws an exception

How am I suppose to do this properly? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` and `size` functions from [pyspark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions):

```
df.filter(size(split(col('text'), ' ')) > 10).show()
```